# Trackpoint on Lenovo T460p in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, trackpoint

I've got a new Lenovo Thinkpad T460P, but I do not get the Trackpoint working in Ubuntu like I want it to ...

It did work for like a week after I installed Ubuntu, then, without any change (or at least I don't remember any), it started to "break".

The first thing I noticed was: The Trackpoint only worked as a scroll wheel, i. e. I could scroll by moving the Trackpoint, but had to use the keyboard to enable the touchpad to continue using my laptop.

Now, no matter what I try (I tried some change in the Xorg config, I tried `modprobe psmouse proto=bare`, `modprobe psmouse proto=imps` and countless other solutions.

It never works correctly - either, the buttons on the track point don't work at all and I have to use the touchpad, or, the track point and it's buttons work just fine, but whenever I click the left or right button while moving the trackpoint it behaves as if I had clicked the middle button - it pastes the clipboard contents. Also, sometimes the left button behaves as if I would hold it down and I'm constantly dragging files around when trying to move my cursor...

I've tried countless tutorials, hacks with xinput, whatever to get that trackpoint running - there has to be a solution since it worked a week ago ...

It can't be the hardware since `xev` correctly displays all three pressed buttons and correctly recognizes the trackpoint in all four directions...

I know that this question has already been asked here a few times but none of the results worked for me ...

Comment: You should make a copy of the apt logs, note which packages have been updated during that time and check if it still works as expected on an installation where the packages haven't been updated to these versions (e.g. a new install or run from a live cd). Step by step instructions of what to test would be useful for other with similar or the same hardware to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The last comment in this Lenovo support thread suggests that it is due to faulty hardware: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/tp01_en/thread-id/109005/page/3